# Is default rails controller#action execution time reliable and correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance-testing

to test my time of execution I use this code:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'process_action.action_controller' do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
  puts "Event received: #{event.duration}"
end
```

For a request which takes 137ms , it shows just 34ms but I saw in postman and pingdom it takes 137ms.

So where is rest of the 100ms time taking?

See in screenshot:
[image: Rails Log]

It says the request took 25ms, but in post man it took 90ms, so where did the rest of 65ms went?

I know its because of network and internet speed also matters for complete render.

I just wanna confirm that this is the correct time or something is missing here, for example if ApplicationController has a filter:

```
before_action :method_name
```

Then is it considering the action "method_name" also or just the current action ?

Comment: The request also needs to go through Rack, the Rack middleware and the Rails router before your controller is even called. Middleware can also be injected after Rails in the stack (such as caching).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So where is rest of the 100ms time taking?

Latency. It takes time for request to travel from your postman (or pingdom) instance to the server (and back). Rails server has no way of knowing about these delays (in fact, they don't exist as far as it is concerned), therefore it doesn't include them.

Regarding your screenshot:

> [image: Rails Log]

It doesn't include any before_action or such filters of the controller. So if your filters are taking time, they won't be considered in this.

So you should use this:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'process_action.action_controller' do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
  puts "Event received: #{event.duration}"
end
```

This will include the time spent in filters also.

Comment: Oh, and `before_action :method_name` doesn't say anything about action `method_name`. It applies to all actions. Not sure why this in the question.

Comment: I mean there are filters in ApplicationController, like before_action, around_action, etc. What if those actions are the ones taking time? Maybe the actual action is taking 500ms, but before_action is taking 2 minutes, so total render time is coming out to be 2.5 seconds because of that? I mean does the value show in screenshot (which is 25ms) considers all kinds of filters also or not ? I mean does include the filters of Application Controller also?

Comment: @user1735921: ah, I see. I would guess that request time includes filters, yes. But I'm not 100% certain on this. Trivial to check, though. Put a `sleep(2)` in one of your filters and see how it affects reported time.

Comment: @user1735921: oh, and let's get terminology straignt. A `before_action` filter/hook is not an action, so don't call it that, to avoid confusion.

Comment: just checked, it doesn't include, but ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe does. screenshot doesn't.